# Rails App - Digital Ocean We're sorry, but something went wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, digital-ocean

I upload some changes yesterday using git as usual (to the master branch).

I used: `sudo service unicorn_archgard-cms stop` and after run some migrations and precompile some assets I used: `sudo service unicorn_archgard-cms start`

The application starts but when I go to the Ip address I have the message: "We're sorry, but something went wrong.".

This is my `shared/log/unicorn.stderr.log` message:

```
I, [2016-04-19T18:54:30.022389 #32494]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2016-04-19T18:54:33.605282 #32494]  INFO -- : listening on addr=/home/deploy/trid-cms/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fd=12
I, [2016-04-19T18:54:33.605492 #32494]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2016-04-19T18:54:33.610021 #32494]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawning...
I, [2016-04-19T18:54:33.612307 #32498]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=32498
I, [2016-04-19T18:54:33.612575 #32498]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
I, [2016-04-19T18:54:33.614936 #32494]  INFO -- : master process ready
I, [2016-04-19T18:54:33.615991 #32501]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawned pid=32501
I, [2016-04-19T18:54:33.616242 #32501]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
I, [2016-04-19T18:56:50.818196 #32494]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 32498 exit 0> worker=0
I, [2016-04-19T18:56:50.818454 #32494]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 32501 exit 0> worker=1
I, [2016-04-19T18:56:50.818695 #32494]  INFO -- : master complete
I, [2016-04-19T18:57:01.432867 #312]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2016-04-19T18:57:04.834900 #312]  INFO -- : unlinking existing socket=/home/deploy/trid-cms/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock
I, [2016-04-19T18:57:04.835353 #312]  INFO -- : listening on addr=/home/deploy/trid-cms/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fd=12
I, [2016-04-19T18:57:04.835511 #312]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2016-04-19T18:57:04.839000 #312]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawning...
I, [2016-04-19T18:57:04.840522 #316]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=316
I, [2016-04-19T18:57:04.840892 #316]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
I, [2016-04-19T18:57:04.842341 #312]  INFO -- : master process ready
I, [2016-04-19T18:57:04.847809 #319]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawned pid=319
I, [2016-04-19T18:57:04.848027 #319]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
I, [2016-04-19T19:06:26.420911 #312]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 316 exit 0> worker=0
I, [2016-04-19T19:06:26.421128 #312]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 319 exit 0> worker=1
I, [2016-04-19T19:06:26.421284 #312]  INFO -- : master complete
```

At this point, I don't know what is happening. I check in my entire code in order to find errors in the code (but in local is working fine).

Comment: Show please `shared/log/production.log` file

Comment: I just have these two files: "unicorn.stderr.log"  "unicorn.stdout.log". The second one don't have anything inside. I don't have a production.log file.